# Direct2d. Texture atlas creation

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, directx, uwp, direct2d

My goal is to create a texture atlas in my directx application. What i have is a vector of ID2D1PathGeometries which need to to be put on a texture atlas. So i create a ID2D1Bitmap1, but i have no clue on what is my next step. In other words, - how exactly do i lay an ID2D1PathGeometry on a ID2D1Bitmap1 on the spot i need?

p/s/ it worth mentioning, that i'm kind of a newbie in directx and when i try to look for an answer on msdn i just keep getting lost in everything direct2d provides you with. 
TU

p/p/s Code requested:
there is not much to show, as i mentioned already.

```
std::vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry>> atlasGeometries; // so i have my geometries
////than i fill the vector
{
....
}
////Creating Bitmap for font sheet
Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID2D1Bitmap1> bitmap;
D2D1_SIZE_U dimensions;
dimensions.height = 1024;
dimensions.width = 1024;

D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1  d2dbp;
D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT d2dpf;
FLOAT dpiX;
FLOAT dpiY;

d2dpf.format = DXGI_FORMAT_A8_UNORM;
d2dpf.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED;

this->dxDevMt.GetD2DFactory()->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);

d2dbp.pixelFormat = d2dpf;
d2dbp.dpiX = dpiX;
d2dbp.dpiY = dpiY;
d2dbp.bitmapOptions = D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET;
d2dbp.colorContext = nullptr;

newCtx->CreateBitmap(dimensions, nullptr, 0, d2dbp, bitmap.GetAddressOf());
```

But what i do next is a quest for me. i kind of figured out, i should use RenderTarget for such kind of stuff. but i failed to figure out, how exactly.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved via using bitmap as a render target.
The idea is to create a new d2d device
create a new DeviceContext
set Bitmap as a render target
and render everything, thta needs to be rendered